# Weird entry for robots.txt on a Naked Domain in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console, dns, dns-servers, blackhat

We own a *.co.uk* address and use an Internet hosting company that has made mistakes around *DNS* in the past. Our main site is hosted on *www.* and their reluctance to allow editing of *AAAA* records on-line means our naked domain does not resolve.

Currently when we attempt to reach the naked version there is no entry for the browser to go to and it displays an unreachable page (*nslookup* just says Name: *name of domain* with no further entries such as an *IP* or *Canonical Name*).

We recently added the relevant *TXT* records to verify us to view both the *www.* version and the naked version of the domain in *Google Webmaster Tools* (in anticipation of the requests to our Internet host coming to fruition).

Imagine our shock when double checking the *Site configuration > Crawler access* and finding a (admittedly failing) *robots.txt* with a dynamically generated *HTML* page (full of crude pop-up *JavaScript*) with references to 3 of our most prominent competitors.

**What could cause this to happen?**

As we are in the UK I am assuming some *DNS* server is serving Google bad information. We are going to contact the Internet hosting company to fix our *A* and *AAAA* records once and for all, then check that they work in the *US* (using something like *OpenDNS*). Should we be doing more though, for instance informing *Google* (through *Webmaster Tools*) that we are now aware there is something currently wrong with our naked domain?

**UPDATE:**

We have fixed our *A* records (not *AAAA*) and that has resolved the issue. But if there are further actions we should take for effectively having a parking page hosted on our active visitor-heavy, SEO-rich domain that advertised our competitors to US visitors, what would they be?

Comment: Not sure what the problem could be, but why are you still using a web host that won't let you edit your DNS entries and makes errors on them?

Comment: Politics. I personally wouldn't touch them with a 10 foot bargepoll.

Comment: That sounds like an old domain parking page. Does "Fetch as Googlebot" give you any response to the /robots.txt ?

Comment: Not now (as we have addressed the issue) but last night I used Tor to see what it looked like from the US and it was showing a generic parking page.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the URL of the site in question to double-check what happened there (eg what DNS said, which IP address responded to the request, etc)..

Comment: Unfortunately due to the nature of the company I work for, it wouldn't reflect well upon them to reveal such details. Although I appreciate it would be easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Find a new host.

Comment: Moving host now.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question about whether or not to inform Google of this issue: no, this appears to clearly be a technical issue on the hosting side. After resolving it on your side, it'll automatically get resolved as Google recrawls your URLs.

If this were a web-spam issue (which from your description does not appear to be the case), you could submit a [reconsideration request](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35843), but as long as it's a technical issue, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: It was a generic parking page with links to dodgy car insurers and a handful of our prominent competitors.

Comment: @Metalshark: Unfortunately, with the current web hosting/registrar industry, that sort of behavior isn't really out of the ordinary. A lot of registrars and web hosts appropriate inactive domains (e.g. expired registration, parked, or suspended accounts) for their own purposes. Most commonly, they put up ads and essentially squat on the domain, making advertising revenue off of the residual traffic. If the domain is industry-specific, it's conceivable that your competitors showing up could just be a coincidence.

Comment: @Lèse majesté if this was an answer - I would accept it. You're right and we are left to pick up the pieces. Recovery has gone quite well though.